# ¿Están permitidas las preguntas del tipo "¿Graves fallos de seguridad en los procesadores Intel?"?

Tags: discusión, temática, pregunta-específica

En base a la pregunta [¿Graves fallos de seguridad en los procesadores Intel?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/128932/45).

> Apenas empezando 2018 casi todos los medios mundiales se hacen eco de
>   un grave fallo de seguridad en los procesadores Intel fabricados en la
>   última década.
>
> Los medios dicen que la solución pasaría por ralentizar entre un 5% y
>   un 30% los ordenadores afectados mediante una actualización del
>   sistema operativo.
>
> ¿Qué hay de cierto en todo esto? Pondrán las diferentes plataformas de
>   forma clara parches de seguridad para corregir dicho fallo.

---

Sé la gravedad del asunto que involucra la falla de seguridad en los procesadores Intel, pero a raíz de ello hago las siguientes preguntas.

- ¿Está permitido este tipo de preguntas en Stack Overflow?
- ¿Debería considerar como pregunta todo fallo de seguridad que exista en algún **hardware**?
- ¿Acaso este tipo de preguntas no se debería realizar en [Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com)?

> Recordar que Stack Overflow es un sitio utilizado por la comunidad de desarrolladores informáticos, en la cual otros desarrolladores pueden encontrar soluciones a problemas de programación en diferentes lenguajes.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71355/discussion-on-question-by-davlio-estan-permitidas-las-preguntas-del-tipo-grav).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Esta pregunta esta en el sitio equivocado.

Cuando se creo el sitio, se le dio un ambito de preguntas validas, ellas son:

- un problema específico de programación, o
- un algoritmo de software, o
- herramientas de software comúnmente utilizadas por programadores;
- y es un problema práctico, que tiene respuesta y único al desarrollo de software

Esta pregunta, por mas que es muy interesante y tiene que ver relativamente con lo que hacemos, no esta incluida en esta lista.

Si no nos apegamos a la lista, abrimos la puerta a preguntas que tienen que ver con computadoras pero no son sobre programacion, y para las cuales se tiene un sitio particular (aunque este en ingles).

Parafraseando mi comentario:

En cualquier momento van a preguntar sobre cada cuanto tiene que ir un armario al armar una red con cable coaxil y la vamos a aceptar porque tiene que ver con computadoras y esta en español.

Y no. Para esa clase de preguntas, nos guste o no, hay un sitio dedicado. Si nosotros dejamos que se pregunte sobre cualquier cosa que tenga que ver con una computadora, porque tiene que ver con una computadora, entonces esto se va a volver un lio de gente tratando de encontrar preguntas, y lo que eso provoca es que la mayoria de las preguntas terminen sin respuesta.

Se le dio un "SCOPE" al sitio, y fue por algo. Para evitar contestar cosas sobre cualquier cosa. Y justamente, no por moralista, si no por ordenado, es el porque la pregunta debe ser cerrada, y hasta eliminada. Por que no enseña a nuevos usuarios que pueden preguntar, si no que confunde.  Este no es un sitio sobre hardware, y es mas, la pregunta aunque interesante, no es una pregunta por si misma, si no que es una pregunta construida para generar una respuesta. Parece mas un post de un blog que una pregunta para este sitio.

### **Propuesta**

El tema es interesante, y aunque no corresponde particularmente al sitio, es un tema que deberia quedar plasmado, y la pregunta tiene una respuesta excelente. Lo que propongo es proteger la pregunta por parte de un moderador, sin borrarla, pero aclarando que esta protegida porque es un tema que incumbe al conjunto de programadores, pero que esta fuera de la tematica del sitio. Y eliminar la respuesta de ahi, y utilizar el [Blog de SO esp](https://stackoverflow.blog/tags/international/espanol/) y poner toda la entrada de la respuesta ahi, dando el credito correspondiente a Cedano. De esa forma tambien, si ocurre algun cambio, podria ir y modificar tambien dicha entrada.

Seria ideal, tambien, que la pregunta redireccionara al blog (o por lo menos la entrada de la proteccion de la pregunta).

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71318/discussion-on-answer-by-gbianchi-estan-permitidas-las-preguntas-del-tipo-grav).

Comment: Desgraciadamente cedano no pariticipa de los chats (aunque concuerdo con tu desicion de pasar todo)

Answer (score 4):

El conocimiento que ofrecen las respuestas a esta pregunta es fundamental para solventar :

- [un problema práctico, que tiene respuesta y único al desarrollo de software](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Meltdown y Spectre son Sofware. El problema que plantean tiene respuesta. En el caso de Meltdown hay parches y el caso de Spectre es más difícil. Sin duda es un problema único al desarrollo del software.

El problema de cómo desarrollar una arquitectura que no tenga estas vulnerabilidades sería de hardware, pero no es de eso de lo que trata la pregunta.

La pregunta se podría mejorar. Por ejemplo :

> Pondrán las diferentes plataformas de forma clara parches de seguridad
>   para corregir dicho fallo.

Esa es una pregunta sobre lo que harán las plataformas en el futuro. Cualquier respuesta sería especulativa. Pero la temática, qué son Meltdown y Spectre, es muy apropiada para el sitio. Sin duda es apropiada para los entusiastas y programadores de Sistemas Operativos.

> Stack Overflow en español es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas para
>   programadores y entusiastas del desarrollo y uso de software. [Enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 2):

Dado que soy el autor de la pregunta puesta en cuestión, responderé brevemente a tus tres interrogantes:

1. **¿Está permitido este tipo de preguntas en Stack Overflow?**

A mi juicio sí, dado que no se pregunta por la forma de reparar la lavadora de mi casa, sino sobre un problema de considerable trascendencia que ataña no solamente al hardware, sino también al software.

Además, se trata de un problema muy particular que va a tener una trascedencia considerable y los usuarios hispanohablantes tienen derecho a conocer el asunto en su propio idioma.

La pregunta cumple con los siguientes criterios indicados en el apartado: [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

- Trata sobe un problema específico de programación
- Trata sobre herramientas de software comúnmente utilizadas por programadores
- Trata sobre un problema práctico, que tiene respuesta y único al desarrollo de software

---

**2. ¿Debería considerar como pregunta todo fallo de seguridad que exista
en algún hardware?**

No es un fallo de seguridad cualquiera, sino que afecta a las plataformas más usadas actualmente. Un fallo oculto en procesadores desde el año 1995. Se está preguntando por tanto sobre un tema de alta trascendencia.

---

**3. ¿Acaso este tipo de preguntas no se debería realizar en Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange?**

No, porque Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange es un sitio en inglés y no tiene un homólogo en castellano. Si se plantea allí la pregunta sería cerrada por no estar planteada en inglés. Y si se plantea en inglés, sería marcada como duplicada porque la misma ya existe allí.

¿Cómo se beneficiarán de esa información los programadores que no hablan/leen en inglés?

---

### Edición de la pregunta para que sea más acorde con el formato del sitio

La pregunta en cuestión fue modificada, tratando de adaptarla al formato del sitio, quedando planteada ahora de este modo:

**Título:**

> ### ¿En qué consiste el problema de seguridad llamado Meltdown and Spectre? ¿Se podrá corregir a nivel de software?

**Cuerpo de la pregunta:**

> Apenas empezando 2018 casi todos los medios mundiales se hacen eco de
> un grave fallo de seguridad llamado Meltdown and Spectre, que afecta
> de manera especial a los equipos con procesadores Intel.
>
> - ¿En qué consiste Meltdown and Spectre?
> - ¿Se podrá corregir a nivel de software?

En cuanto a la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/128933/29967), ya que se trataba de una auto-respuesta marcada como Wiki de comunidad (no sé si siga teniendo sentido que sea Wiki de comunidad), la misma también fue editada, para responder más adecuadamente a lo preguntado en la nueva edición.

Se agradece cualquier comentario sobre posibles mejoras.

Comment: En base a la edición, me podrías explicar en que parte está relacionado a un tema de desarrollo o los temas que se pueden tocar en Stack Overflow ([¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). En tu opinión, no sería bueno que dicha pregunta lo hagas en otro sitio de Exchange, por ejemplo [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). ¿Has revisado todo los [sitios que tiene stackexchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology) y sabes el propósito del por qué existen?

Comment: @Davlio a mi juicio cumple con los puntos 1, 3 y 4. No conozco todos los sitios de la red y aunque quisiera no tendría tiempo para participar en más sitios porque como he dicho en otras partes, mi actividad principal no es la informática por lo que descarto multiplicar mis participaciones en los otros diferentes sitios.

Comment: Por mi parte no considero que la pregunta esté **orientado a la comunidad de desarrolladores**, más bien es un tema relacionado a la seguridad o infraestructura inclusive, y que en los demás sitios que existe en Exchange se pueda encontrar ese tipo de preguntas. A mi perspectiva cuando un (o un nuevo) participante de la comunidad encuentre ese tipo de preguntas pueda pensar que toda pregunta relacionada a "software" tiene cabida en este sitio y no le damos la oportunidad de explorar los demás sitios que tiene Exchange, los cuales se crean para determinados tipos de preguntas.

Comment: Pensarás que la pregunta es "trascendetal" para toda la comunidad informática y que debido a que los demás sitios están en inglés, al menos se debe dar oportunidad en el sitio; el problema sería no respetar el por qué se crean los sitios de Exchange y su finalidad. Por mi parte solo esperaba tu respuesta a la pregunta hecha en meta, asimismo, ya reporte tu pregunta y como parte de una comunidad estamos para moderar.

Comment: @Davlio no entendí esto: *Por mi parte solo esperaba tu respuesta a la pregunta hecha en meta, asimismo, ya reporte tu pregunta y como parte de una comunidad estamos para moderar.* ¿A qué pregunta esperabas mi respuesta? ¿Qué quieres decir con que reportaste la pregunta? Como quiera que sea, será la comunidad quien decida sobre el asunto, votando a favor o votando en contra.

Comment: En base al sistema de reporte, indiqué el cierre como no relacionado por **Claro contenido no deseado (esta pregunta no tiene nada que ver con Stack Overflow en español)**, ya la comunidad participará o los moderadores verificarán si esta bien el reporte que plantee.

Comment: Perfecto @Davlio, **a mi juicio sí tiene que ver mucho con StackOverflow en español**, de hecho, la plantee por eso. De todos modos, me atendré al resultado final. Saludos.

Comment: Cuando dices: _"Y usarla para intentar darle relevancia al blog, tampoco. Preferiría que la pregunta sea eliminada en ese caso."_. ¿Quieres decir que si no te conviene el "resultado final" vas a eliminar la pregunta? Dónde quedó tus palabras al decir: **"De todos modos, me atendré al resultado final.".**

Comment: @Davlio ***me atendré al resultado final*** significa a lo que decida la comunidad por votos, no a lo que decidan tú y gbianchi de forma imparcial . Para mí trasladarla al blog no es algo que decida la comunidad. Hay un sistema de votos a través del cual se decide si la pregunta se cierra o se abre o se elimina. Si gbianchi o tu consideran que es un tema para el blog entonces deberían ser ustedes los que escriban sobre el asunto en el blog, no yo. Creo que la puntuación actual de la respuesta dada a la pregunta expresa totalmente lo contrario de lo que ustedes dos creen.

Comment: Quién te entiende... Para el punto 1, somos parte de una comunidad y expreso lo que pienso de tu pregunta, por ende (lo recalco nuevamente) **la comunidad participará o los moderadores verificarán si esta bien el reporte que plantee**. Para el punto 2, el traslado a un blog de una pregunta, tienes que entender que toda pregunta que no concuerde con la temática del sitio debe ser moderada por nosotros, como comunidad. Asimismo, eso es una propuesta que lo hace @JuanM, favor de considerar leer sus comentarios.

Comment: Para el punto 3, (recalco nuevamente)  indiqué el cierre como no relacionado por **Claro contenido no deseado (esta pregunta no tiene nada que ver con Stack Overflow en español)**, en ningún momento busqué la migración a un blog. Para el punto final, (lo recalco nuevamente) **la comunidad participará o los moderadores verificarán si esta bien el reporte que plantee**. Para terminar, StackExchange tiene varios sitios y tienen su razón de ser, para tratar temas específicos y por ello cada uno debe ser considerado en el cómo debe participar.

Comment: Lamentable no están en español, pero todos tenemos la oportunidad de proponer en [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810?page=1&phase=beta&users=reputation#tab-top) para que esté en español. Solo espero haberte hecho comprendo (nuevamente) la finalidad de mi participación en la comunidad.

Comment: @Davlio, para ser breve: 1. Quien plantea originalmente trasladarla al blog es gbianchi, no JuanM. 2. Lo que tú llamas **claro contenido no deseado** tiene ahora un total de 12 puntos a favor (entre la pregunta y la respuesta). Así que es contenido no deseado para ti y algunos más, pero no para la mayoría de la comunidad. 3. Entiendo que la red tenga varios sitios, pero muchísimos de ellos sólo existen en inglés. Esa es la realidad **actual**, y mientras se plantee y quizá se apruebe un homólogo en castellano, mientras tanto tu percepción es selectiva y privativa para quien no sabe inglés.

Comment: Solo vuelvo a copiar mi comentario: _"Pensarás que la pregunta es "trascendetal" para toda la comunidad informática y que debido a que los demás sitios están en inglés, al menos se debe dar oportunidad en el sitio; el problema sería no respetar el por qué se crean los sitios de Exchange y su finalidad. Por mi parte solo esperaba tu respuesta a la pregunta hecha en meta, asimismo, ya reporte tu pregunta y como parte de una comunidad estamos para moderar."_

Comment: Sé objetivo @Davlio. La aceptación que han tenido la pregunta y la respuesta indica que la gran mayoría quiere que la pregunta exista aquí, no en otra parte. En cuanto a esta pregunta, quienes la han leído no están de acuerdo contigo. Y no se está irrespetando la razón de ser de otros sitios. Muchos de esos sitios no tienen homólogos en castellano, y aunque los tuvieran, es una pregunta totalmente adecuada para SO en español. No estoy preguntando por cómo se repara una lavadora, para que tú y 3 más se rasguen las vestiduras por esta pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Recalco: _"la comunidad participará o los moderadores verificarán si esta bien el reporte que plantee"_

Comment: No exactamente @Davlio. Si SO es un sitio abierto, tienes que cambiar la `o` por una `y`: *la comunidad participará **y** los moderadores verificarán si esta bien el reporte que plantee*, tomando en cuenta (supongo) la valoración que se ha hecho del contenido por parte de los usuarios.

Answer (score 1):

Llego un poco tarde al tema, pero en mi opinión esta pregunta/respuesta está muy en el límite de lo que debe de ser aceptable en el sitio.

Básicamente, Stack Overflow en español es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas, orientado a dar soluciones a los programadores.

Por qué la pregunta para mi esta fuera de tema no tiene nada que ver con el tema en si, sino con que es no es una pregunta que pueda tener una respuesta útil que solucione el problema. Es simplemente una información que ya se puede encontrar en numerosos artículos y blogs. Si aceptamos preguntas de este tipo, abrimos la posibilidad a convertir el sitio en un blog de noticias de informática, lo que no es el objetivo en mi opinión.

Digo que no tiene nada que ver con el tema por lo siguiente: Si un empleado de Microsoft hiciera una pregunta exponiendo el problema y preguntando de que manera se podría hacer un parche para solucionar las vulnerabilidades, si sería una pregunta válida para el sitio (obviando por supuesto que se pudiera considerar demasiado amplia). Pero en este caso, es una exposición de en que consisten dichas vulnerabilidades y que la solución depende de unos parches que deben proporcionar las compañías desarrolladoras de los diferentes Sistemas Operativos.

Resumiendo, aunque es lógicamente una información de interés para todos los usuarios de ordenadores, me parece que es mas una noticia que una pregunta aceptable dentro del sitio.

**Edicion:**

Tras una discusión en el chat, veo necesario aclarar que mi opinión se basa en considerar la pregunta/respuesta en conjunto, ya que así fue como se planteó.

Si aislo la pregunta y la tomo individualmente, podría estar levemente dentro de tema. Pero, aun así...¿existe alguna respuesta posible que sea válida para el formato del sitio? En mi opinión no, y por eso sigo considerando que no es válida.